# access variables of other functions

Tags: python, function, variables, global-variables

in python, how can i access the variables of one function into another function, is it possible, i tried the global variable method but that doesn't work for me.

can someone help me, how to access the variables from one function to another function.

Comment: could you not just pass the variable needed?

Comment: Why didn't the global variable method work for you? Can you post the code?

Comment: i want to access the variables with their values, let me explain:



def func_a():
     A_list= ["john", "david", "mike", "emmy"]


def func_b():


you can see the func_a contains a list A_list which has values in it

now i wanna access the values in that A_list which is in func_a() in the func_b(), how can i do that ?

Comment: In your example A_list is a local variable that only exists while func_a is executing - it will vanish when the function ends.  So it is unlikely to be around to be accessed when func_b runs.   Whatever it is you actually want to do, this is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share data between functions then create a class and turn the functions into methods on the class.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do this. Explicit is better than implicit - if your function needs access to certain variables, pass them in. If it needs to change a value in the calling function, return the new value.

Comment: hi daniel, can you give some example, because i am once again stuck in an another project, and i don't have enough time to recode the whole project left by my senior, can you please help me with some example.